# What is the best way to implement mixed ASP.NET forms auth (AD + DB)?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I want to implement forms authentication on an ASP.NET website, the site should seek the user on the database to get some data and then authenticate against LDAP (Active Directory) to validate the user/password combo.

After that I need to keep a instance of class that represents the user to use it in various forms.

I tried to do it before with a login control, that checks the previous conditions and do an `AuthenticateEventArgs.Authenticated = true` and placed the object inside the session: `Session ["user"] = authenticatedUser;` but I had problem synchronizing both of them (the session expired before the auth cookie and I got NullReferenceExceptions when the pages tried to use the now defunct session object).

Which is the best way to accomplish this? Is there some way to sync the session timeout with the cookie lifespan? The user object should be saved in any other way? Did I miss the point?

**UPDATE: 
I cannot use windows auth provider because the site should be accesible from outside out priate network.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Windows Authentication as the main authentication provider, but roll my own simple database persistence for user information.

Your session method would work, you can adjust session timeout in IIS and match it to the authentication cookie timeout.

Also, you can do something like this in a HTTPModule to catch edge cases (app pool recycles etc) that also clear session

Psuedocode:

```
if (session["user"] == null)
{
    Authentication.SignOut();
}
```

This would force the user to authenticate.

Comment: HTTPModule? could you tell me more about it?

Comment: I'd do it on Application_BeginRequest in global.asax

HttpModules are basically compiling global.asax into seperate dll's. Good for modularity

Comment: Why is better Begin_Request than Session_end?

Comment: If Session is gone, you want to redirect to the authentication page immediately.

Comment: But when session is gone shouldn't the forms take care of that if i do FormsAuthetincation.Signout () ?

Answer (score 0):

I set the session and auth cookie timeout values to the same value.  I use sliding windows for my auth cookie.  I also make it a habit to never assume that values I get out of the session are non-null before attempting to use them.  I often abstract all of the session functionality out into a proxy class that contains strongly typed properties for the values I store in the session.  The error handling for bad session data is localized in the proxy.

Comment: So, there's no elegant and automatic way to always have them synced together?

Answer (score 0):

Storing the user info in the session will work fine.  To sync session timeout and auth cookie timeout, just edit your web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="XX" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="XX" />
</authentication>
```

Both values are in minutes.

Test for null EVERY time you get a value from the Session!

Comment: why should i test for null? what's so unrealiable about the session that you cannot trust the value wich should contain?